# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name return LocalSqlServer

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web service and I call the WCF method with `Ajax` (`JQuery`).

I tested my web service with `WcfTestClient.exe` and it works well.

But when I call the web service method with `Jquery`, I have an error (**object reference not set to an instance of an object**).

I debug and I have this in my `**ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name** : *LocalSqlServer*`.

My dataBase key is RMS and not LocalSqlServer.

I have 2 projects in my solution, the WCF and an application console that will do to turn back the web service.

Here my solution

[image]

Here is my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RMS" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.40.137;Initial Catalog=RMS_Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="16384"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />  
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I created a `.asmx` web service and I succeeded `JQuery` calls.
I think my solution is not using the correct `web.config.` How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I also added the connectionstrings in app.config of the **GettingStartedHost** project and now it works well.

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 14):

Your first post is probably just missing the following entry:

```
<clear />
```

Before the following entry:

```
 <add name="RMS" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.40.137;Initial Catalog=RMS_Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Description: Without the clear entry the default machine.config connection string is read. This entry is called LocalSqlServer. Clear avoids this.

Comment: perfect , could you please let me know if we need that `LocalSqlServer` in any circumstances ?